# Return a Mocha result to GitHub Actions via docker-compose

Tags: docker, unit-testing, docker-compose, mocha.js, github-actions

I have to setup some unit tests on my project.
Tey're linked to a MongoDB, but it have an IP whitelist, so I built a node container and a mongo container on Docker, and used docker-compose to do my test.
Actually, they're working.

BUT

When the tests are done (and passing), the docker container keep running and it's not returning the result to GitHub Actions

I want to, when my test are passing, return to gitAction that they're passed and make the GitHub Actions test "passed", and when my tests are failing, do the same thing but say to GitHub Actions that the tests failed.

Can anyone help me with that?

EDIT :

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  api:
    container_name: api
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    links:
      - mongodb
  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

And this is my github action workflow (node.js.yml)

```
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master", "unit-test" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master", "unit-test" ]
  
jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [12.x, 14.x, 16.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'npm'
    - name: Start Docker
      run: docker-compose build
    - run: docker-compose up --target api
```

Comment: Please show your YAML and ideally create a [minimal reproducer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Edited, please tell me if you need more information :)

Comment: Have you tried [`docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/faq/#whats-the-difference-between-up-run-and-start)?

Comment: I didn't, but what's the difference?

Comment: I just did, and I have the same problem... Docker won't stop or return anything to GitHub Actions. I can see the output, but I want GitHub Action to be successful (or not) if the tests are successful

Answer (score 0):

docker-compose has an option `--exit-code-from` to wrap it up when one container finishes.

`docker-compose up --exit-code-from api`

Also I think you will need to remove `restart: always`. Maybe creating a separate `docker-compose` yaml file for this testing purposes is a good idea too.

Comment: I tried with --exit-code-from api, but still not returning anything.

But I think my issue come from my node testing. The fact is that, when I start my tests with "npm test", the terminal doesn't stop anyway, so I guess I have to find a way to terminate it when all tests are over

Comment: That's common too. You probably don't close all your open connections and mocha doesn't finish. A temp solution is adding - - exit to your mocha command. But in reality you should try to figure out what's happening using something like wtfnode